# How to put shading 'on' on 1 line and 'off' on the next line in ms-word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I try to write code for getting data out of Excel and in to a word document. Getting the data in Word is no problem, but I'm stuck at formatting the layout.

I want a Header with shading: a black blackground and the text in white. And on the line after this no shading and text in black.

I recorded a macro in Word, did what I wanted it to look like and looked at the code. But I can't get it to work. At first the code turns shading on for the whole document and afterwards it turns it 'off' for the whole document. I can't get it to apply it only to the first rule in the Word document.

Here is my Code:

```
'Setting up Word
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = New Word.Application

WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate
WordApp.Documents.Add


With WordApp.Selection
    .Font.Size = 30
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdWhite
    .TypeText "Heading"
    .ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .TypeParagraph
    .Font.Size = 12
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
    .Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    .Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .TypeText "Meeting Date"
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With

'Kill the object
'WordApp.Quit
'Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Has anyone got suggestions? Thanks in advance.

With the comment made by cybernetic.nomad I adjusted the code and now it does what I want.

```
With WordApp.Selection
    .Font.Size = 30
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdWhite
    .TypeText "Heading"
End With
WordApp.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

With WordApp.Selection
    .TypeParagraph
    .Font.Size = 12
    .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
    .TypeText "Meeting Date"
End With
WordApp.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Down change the colour on the whole selection, use just the first paragraph (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Selection.Paragraphs)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I Adjusted the code to what I think you were saying. Now the code does what I want. Thanks!